# How to pull Whitelisted URLs for SafeLinks policy via Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Microsoft's SafeLinks feature in Exchange and Exchange Online will do a standard in-line re-direction for any links in an e-mail. The policy setting for this feature allows the admin to whitelist specific URLs and domains, which will then not get wrapped by SafeLinks.

I used to be able to pull this listed of whitelisted URLs for SafeLinks via PowerShell and the ExchangeOnlineManagement module:

`Get-SafeLinksPolicy | select -expandproperty WhiteListedUrls > whitelistedurls.txt`

But now I get errors instead:

```
At line:1 char:23
+ Get-SafeLinksPolicy | select -expandproperty WhiteListedUrls
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Built-In Protection Policy:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

I've tried finding how to do this in all of the docs on Microsoft's website but to no avail. This absolutely did work six or months less ago.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

And turns out the solution is simply that the renamed the property that holds the list of whitelisted URLs to "DoNotRewriteUrls"

Correct and functional powershell to use:

`Get-SafeLinksPolicy | select -expandproperty DoNotRewriteUrls`